# Determine if two strings are anagram?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int comp(const void *a, const void *b);

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    char s1[]="";
    char s2[]="";
    char *fmt = "%[^\n]%*c";

    printf("Enter the first word? ");
    scanf(fmt,&s1);

    printf("Enter the second word? ");
    scanf(fmt,&s2);

    qsort(s1, strlen(s1), 1, comp);
    qsort(s2, strlen(s2), 1, comp);

    printf("%s : %s  - %s\n", s1, s2, strcmp(s1, s2) ? "No" : "Yes");
    return 0;
}

static int comp(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    const char *pa = (char*)a;
    const char *pb = (char*)b;

    return
        (*pa > *pb) ?  1 :
        (*pa < *pb) ? -1 :
        0;
}
```

When I key in 'smartest' as my first string and 'mattress' as my second string , my output becomes

```
emrsstt : aemrsstt - No
```

Why is the first character of the string missing?

Been sitting on this for hours. Gladly appreciate if someone could point out the silly mistake I may have made.

Comment: `char s1[]="";` makes an array that's only big enough for a zero-length string (it has room for a NUL terminator only). You need to allocate enough space for your actual strings. Right now you're overflowing the arrays and experiencing undefined behavior.

Comment: The size of `s1` and `s2` is 1. Scanning a string into any of them means you're overriding some memory, leading to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A smart way of doing this is to first check for a *probable anagram*. You do this by

1. Comparing the string lengths.
2. XORing every `char` from the total set; drawn from both strings.

If the result of (2) is not zero then the strings cannot possibly be anagrams. The advantage of doing this is that (2) is extremely fast in c and most strings are not anagrams, even if they are the same length. If your feeling particularly ambitious, you *could* combine (1) and (2) into a single O(N) algorithm!

Once you've done that, call your main code body. Your problem is in not allowing for the *null terminator* on each string. Your need to allocate enough space for the string characters plus one extra element for the null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you have to check whether any 2 set of values are same or not XOR operation is helpful.

```
Input   Output
A   B
0   0   0
0   1   1
1   0   1
1   1   0
```

So using this we can solve your problem as done below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0,f;
char a[30] = "gooo";
char b[30] = "ooog";

if(strlen(a) == strlen(b))
{
  while(a[i] != '\0')
  {
j = 0;
f =0;
     while(b[j] != '\0')
     {
         if( !(a[i] ^ b[j]) )
         {
           f =1;
           break;
         }
         j++;
     }
     if(f)
     i++;
     else
     break;
  }
printf("%d\n",i);
if(i == strlen(a))
printf("Yes\n");
else
printf("No\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check and the below solution for the anagram problem. This solution checks if two strings have identical counts for each unique char

```
bool anagram (char s[], char t[])
{
    if (strlen(s) != strlen(t)){
      return false;
    }

    int letters[256];
    memset(letters,(int)0,sizeof(letters));

    int numUniqueChars = 0;
    int numCompletedT = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < strlen(s); i++){
      if (letters[(int)s[i]]==0){  
         ++numUniqueChars;
      }
      letters[s[i]]=letters[s[i]]+1;
    }

    for (i=0; i < strlen(t); i++){
        int c = (int)t[i]; 
        if (letters[c] == 0){
          return false;
        }
        letters[c]=letters[c]-1;

        if (letters[c] == 0){
           numCompletedT++;
           if (numUniqueChars==numCompletedT){
               return i == strlen(t)-1;
           }
        }
    }
  return false;
```

}